# How to add Laravel localization using php file?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I followed the documentation in https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization.

I changed my `'locale'` and `'fallback_locale'` to `'fr'` in `config/app.php`.

The French translation works if I use:
`/lang/fr.json`, but it doesn't work if I use `/lang/fr/messages.php`.

No error messages nor warning, it just stays in English.

What did I miss?

Comment: please show the code of messages, we can't just know like this.

Comment: Plain vanilla Laravel, nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laravel docs could use some sprucing up.

They just need to make it clear: `/lang/fr/messages.php` only works when you add that file's prefix.

Like, if there's a key `Dashboard` in `/lang/fr/messages.php`, you gotta use `{{ __('messages.Dashboard') }}` to call it.

```
// File: /lang/fr/messages.php
<?php
return [
    'Dashboard' => 'FR_Dashboard in French!',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you don't have `resources/lang` .
- `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`
- if above command not working then add `app()->setLocale('fr')` in your middleware or any service provider.